# I checked out to my C drive and now all my folders have?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out a project to the root of my C: drive by mistake, making the whole drive a repository, and now all my root folders have question marks. I deleted the `.svn` folder on my C: drive but I still get the question marks :/

How do I unversion my C drive? xD

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works but maybe you could try deleting your thumbnail cache and restarting.
There's a tutorial on [How to clear the thumbnail cache in windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10797-thumbnail-cache-clear-reset.html)

Comment: @Liminic I did a disk cleanup and removed the thumbnails but with no luck :(

Comment: @user3345413 if there's a less important folder, try opening the settings for it, change icon and click on restore default. If it works, do the same for all folders.

Comment: Restore default doesn't change anything. I think my C: drive is still versioned somehow.

Comment: @user3345413 Maybe this article about [Moving and Removing repositories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.moving-and-removing.html) in Subversion will help you